# Windows API: Wait for data to be available on non-GUI console input (PIPE-based STDIN)

Tags: c, windows, winapi, mingw, stdin

**Background**

I am currently working on a Windows select-like function that not only supports SOCKET handles, but also other kinds of waitable handles. My goal is to wait on standard console handles in order to provide select-functionality to the [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) [testsuite](http://curl.haxx.se/dev/testcurl.html).

The related program can be found in the curl git repository: [sockfilt.c](https://github.com/bagder/curl/blob/master/tests/server/sockfilt.c)

**Question**

Is it possible to wait for data to be available on a non-GUI-based console input? The issue is that [WaitFor*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687028.aspx) methods do not support PIPE handles and therefore STDIN is not supported if the process input is fed from another process, e.g. using the pipe | functionality of cmd.

---

The following example program illustrates the problem: select_ws.c

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <malloc.h>

#include <conio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define SET_SOCKERRNO(x)  (WSASetLastError((int)(x)))

typedef SOCKET curl_socket_t;

/*
 * select function with support for WINSOCK2 sockets and all
 * other handle types supported by WaitForMultipleObjectsEx.
 * http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687028.aspx
 * http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741572.aspx
 */
static int select_ws(int nfds, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds,
                     fd_set *exceptfds, struct timeval *timeout)
{
  long networkevents;
  DWORD milliseconds, wait, idx, avail, events, inputs;
  WSAEVENT wsaevent, *wsaevents;
  WSANETWORKEVENTS wsanetevents;
  INPUT_RECORD *inputrecords;
  HANDLE handle, *handles;
  curl_socket_t sock, *fdarr, *wsasocks;
  int error, fds;
  DWORD nfd = 0, wsa = 0;
  int ret = 0;

  /* check if the input value is valid */
  if(nfds < 0) {
    SET_SOCKERRNO(EINVAL);
    return -1;
  }

  /* check if we got descriptors, sleep in case we got none */
  if(!nfds) {
    Sleep((timeout->tv_sec * 1000) + (timeout->tv_usec / 1000));
    return 0;
  }

  /* allocate internal array for the original input handles */
  fdarr = malloc(nfds * sizeof(curl_socket_t));
  if(fdarr == NULL) {
    SET_SOCKERRNO(ENOMEM);
    return -1;
  }

  /* allocate internal array for the internal event handles */
  handles = malloc(nfds * sizeof(HANDLE));
  if(handles == NULL) {
    SET_SOCKERRNO(ENOMEM);
    return -1;
  }

  /* allocate internal array for the internal socket handles */
  wsasocks = malloc(nfds * sizeof(curl_socket_t));
  if(wsasocks == NULL) {
    SET_SOCKERRNO(ENOMEM);
    return -1;
  }

  /* allocate internal array for the internal WINSOCK2 events */
  wsaevents = malloc(nfds * sizeof(WSAEVENT));
  if(wsaevents == NULL) {
    SET_SOCKERRNO(ENOMEM);
    return -1;
  }

  /* loop over the handles in the input descriptor sets */
  for(fds = 0; fds < nfds; fds++) {
    networkevents = 0;
    handles[nfd] = 0;

    if(FD_ISSET(fds, readfds))
      networkevents |= FD_READ|FD_ACCEPT|FD_CLOSE;

    if(FD_ISSET(fds, writefds))
      networkevents |= FD_WRITE|FD_CONNECT;

    if(FD_ISSET(fds, exceptfds))
      networkevents |= FD_OOB;

    /* only wait for events for which we actually care */
    if(networkevents) {
      fdarr[nfd] = (curl_socket_t)fds;
      if(fds == fileno(stdin)) {
        handles[nfd] = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
      }
      else if(fds == fileno(stdout)) {
        handles[nfd] = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
      }
      else if(fds == fileno(stderr)) {
        handles[nfd] = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);
      }
      else {
        wsaevent = WSACreateEvent();
        if(wsaevent != WSA_INVALID_EVENT) {
          error = WSAEventSelect(fds, wsaevent, networkevents);
          if(error != SOCKET_ERROR) {
            handles[nfd] = wsaevent;
            wsasocks[wsa] = (curl_socket_t)fds;
            wsaevents[wsa] = wsaevent;
            wsa++;
          }
          else {
            handles[nfd] = (HANDLE)fds;
            WSACloseEvent(wsaevent);
          }
        }
      }
      nfd++;
    }
  }

  /* convert struct timeval to milliseconds */
  if(timeout) {
    milliseconds = ((timeout->tv_sec * 1000) + (timeout->tv_usec / 1000));
  }
  else {
    milliseconds = INFINITE;
  }

  /* wait for one of the internal handles to trigger */
  wait = WaitForMultipleObjectsEx(nfd, handles, FALSE, milliseconds, FALSE);

  /* loop over the internal handles returned in the descriptors */
  for(idx = 0; idx < nfd; idx++) {
    fds = fdarr[idx];
    handle = handles[idx];
    sock = (curl_socket_t)fds;

    /* check if the current internal handle was triggered */
    if(wait != WAIT_FAILED && (wait - WAIT_OBJECT_0) >= idx &&
       WaitForSingleObjectEx(handle, 0, FALSE) == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
      /* try to handle the event with STD* handle functions */
      if(fds == fileno(stdin)) {
        /* check if there is no data in the input buffer */
        if(!stdin->_cnt) {
          /* check if we are getting data from a PIPE */
          if(!GetConsoleMode(handle, &avail)) {
            /* check if there is no data from PIPE input */
            if(!PeekNamedPipe(handle, NULL, 0, NULL, &avail, NULL))
              avail = 0;
            if(!avail)
              FD_CLR(sock, readfds);
          } /* check if there is no data from keyboard input */
          else if (!_kbhit()) {
            /* check if there are INPUT_RECORDs in the input buffer */
            if(GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents(handle, &events)) {
              if(events > 0) {
                /* remove INPUT_RECORDs from the input buffer */
                inputrecords = (INPUT_RECORD*)malloc(events *
                                                     sizeof(INPUT_RECORD));
                if(inputrecords) {
                  if(!ReadConsoleInput(handle, inputrecords,
                                       events, &inputs))
                    inputs = 0;
                  free(inputrecords);
                }

                /* check if we got all inputs, otherwise clear buffer */
                if(events != inputs)
                  FlushConsoleInputBuffer(handle);
              }
            }

            /* remove from descriptor set since there is no real data */
            FD_CLR(sock, readfds);
          }
        }

        /* stdin is never ready for write or exceptional */
        FD_CLR(sock, writefds);
        FD_CLR(sock, exceptfds);
      }
      else if(fds == fileno(stdout) || fds == fileno(stderr)) {
        /* stdout and stderr are never ready for read or exceptional */
        FD_CLR(sock, readfds);
        FD_CLR(sock, exceptfds);
      }
      else {
        /* try to handle the event with the WINSOCK2 functions */
        error = WSAEnumNetworkEvents(fds, NULL, &wsanetevents);
        if(error != SOCKET_ERROR) {
          /* remove from descriptor set if not ready for read/accept/close */
          if(!(wsanetevents.lNetworkEvents & (FD_READ|FD_ACCEPT|FD_CLOSE)))
            FD_CLR(sock, readfds);

          /* remove from descriptor set if not ready for write/connect */
          if(!(wsanetevents.lNetworkEvents & (FD_WRITE|FD_CONNECT)))
            FD_CLR(sock, writefds);

          /* remove from descriptor set if not exceptional */
          if(!(wsanetevents.lNetworkEvents & FD_OOB))
            FD_CLR(sock, exceptfds);
        }
      }

      /* check if the event has not been filtered using specific tests */
      if(FD_ISSET(sock, readfds) || FD_ISSET(sock, writefds) ||
         FD_ISSET(sock, exceptfds)) {
        ret++;
      }
    }
    else {
      /* remove from all descriptor sets since this handle did not trigger */
      FD_CLR(sock, readfds);
      FD_CLR(sock, writefds);
      FD_CLR(sock, exceptfds);
    }
  }

  for(idx = 0; idx < wsa; idx++) {
    WSAEventSelect(wsasocks[idx], NULL, 0);
    WSACloseEvent(wsaevents[idx]);
  }

  free(wsaevents);
  free(wsasocks);
  free(handles);
  free(fdarr);

  return ret;
}

int main(void)
{
  WORD wVersionRequested;
  WSADATA wsaData;
  SOCKET sock[4];
  struct sockaddr_in sockaddr[4];
  fd_set readfds;
  fd_set writefds;
  fd_set exceptfds;
  SOCKET maxfd = 0;
  int selfd = 0;
  void *buffer = malloc(1024);
  ssize_t nread;

  setmode(fileno(stdin), O_BINARY);

  wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
  WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);

  sock[0] = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
  sockaddr[0].sin_family = AF_INET;
  sockaddr[0].sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("74.125.134.26");
  sockaddr[0].sin_port = htons(25);
  connect(sock[0], (struct sockaddr *) &sockaddr[0], sizeof(sockaddr[0]));

  sock[1] = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
  sockaddr[1].sin_family = AF_INET;
  sockaddr[1].sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("74.125.134.27");
  sockaddr[1].sin_port = htons(25);
  connect(sock[1], (struct sockaddr *) &sockaddr[1], sizeof(sockaddr[1]));

  sock[2] = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
  sockaddr[2].sin_family = AF_INET;
  sockaddr[2].sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
  sockaddr[2].sin_port = htons(1337);
  printf("bind = %d\n", bind(sock[2], (struct sockaddr *) &sockaddr[2], sizeof(sockaddr[2])));
  printf("listen = %d\n", listen(sock[2], 5));

  sock[3] = INVALID_SOCKET;

  while(1) {
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_ZERO(&writefds);
    FD_ZERO(&exceptfds);

    FD_SET(sock[0], &readfds);
    FD_SET(sock[0], &exceptfds);
    maxfd = maxfd > sock[0] ? maxfd : sock[0];

    FD_SET(sock[1], &readfds);
    FD_SET(sock[1], &exceptfds);
    maxfd = maxfd > sock[1] ? maxfd : sock[1];

    FD_SET(sock[2], &readfds);
    FD_SET(sock[2], &exceptfds);
    maxfd = maxfd > sock[2] ? maxfd : sock[2];

    FD_SET((SOCKET)fileno(stdin), &readfds);
    maxfd = maxfd > (SOCKET)fileno(stdin) ? maxfd : (SOCKET)fileno(stdin);

    printf("maxfd = %d\n", maxfd);
    selfd = select_ws(maxfd + 1, &readfds, &writefds, &exceptfds, NULL);
    printf("selfd = %d\n", selfd);

    if(FD_ISSET(sock[0], &readfds)) {
      printf("read sock[0]\n");
      nread = recv(sock[0], buffer, 1024, 0);
      printf("read sock[0] = %d\n", nread);
    }
    if(FD_ISSET(sock[0], &exceptfds)) {
      printf("exception sock[0]\n");
    }

    if(FD_ISSET(sock[1], &readfds)) {
      printf("read sock[1]\n");
      nread = recv(sock[1], buffer, 1024, 0);
      printf("read sock[1] = %d\n", nread);
    }
    if(FD_ISSET(sock[1], &exceptfds)) {
      printf("exception sock[1]\n");
    }

    if(FD_ISSET(sock[2], &readfds)) {
      if(sock[3] != INVALID_SOCKET)
        closesocket(sock[3]);

      printf("accept sock[2] = %d\n", sock[2]);
      nread = sizeof(sockaddr[3]);
      printf("WSAGetLastError = %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
      sock[3] = accept(sock[2], (struct sockaddr *) &sockaddr[3], &nread);
      printf("WSAGetLastError = %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
      printf("accept sock[2] = %d\n", sock[3]);
    }
    if(FD_ISSET(sock[2], &exceptfds)) {
      printf("exception sock[2]\n");
    }

    if(FD_ISSET(fileno(stdin), &readfds)) {
      printf("read fileno(stdin)\n");
      nread = read(fileno(stdin), buffer, 1024);
      printf("read fileno(stdin) = %d\n", nread);
    }
  }

  WSACleanup();
  free(buffer);
}
```

Compile using MinGW with the following command:

```
mingw32-gcc select_ws.c -Wl,-lws2_32 -g -o select_ws.exe
```

Running the program directly from the console using the following command works:

```
select_ws.exe
```

But doing the same with a pipe will constantly signal WaitForMultipleObjectsEx:

```
ping -t 8.8.8.8 | select_ws.exe
```

The pipe is ready to read until the parent process is finished, e.g.:

```
ping 8.8.8.8 | select_ws.exe
```

---

Is there a compatible way to simulate a blocking wait on the PIPE-based console input handle together with the other handles? The use of threads should be avoided.

You are welcome to contribute changes to the example program in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/4478231).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe that the only supported way to block on an inherited pipe is to read from it, so you may have no choice but to use a thread.  Even with a thread this may not be possible depending on how the calling program's I/O is handled. (Side note: I don't think it is meaningful to wait on the console output handle.)

Comment: You are right, since I want to emulate a select() function, I am not allowed to read any data from the input, because I have nowhere to put it. (Regarding the side note: You may be right. I did not test this part yet and only added it for the sake of completeness.)

Comment: It might be possible (again, depending on the exact context) to create your own pipe and substitute it for the original one, then feed the data over that.  I'm pretty sure you'd need a thread though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found a way to make it work using a separate waiting-thread. Please see the following [commit](https://github.com/bagder/curl/commit/49b63cf30d4242b51bd49295f9f20cfbfb641a7d) in the curl repository on github.com.

Thanks for your comments!

Comment: I recently improved my solution to properly handle disk files, pipes and character input. Please see [these commits](https://github.com/bagder/curl/compare/ee6791128fce28277671ea378104050cf130d2f2...8ce852a279985520ee4bcc4d1357a1612159afc5) to the curl repository or [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mback2k/4478231).

Answer (score 1):

Use `GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)` to get the STDIN pipe handle, then use `ReadFile/Ex()` with an `OVERLAPPED` structure whose `hEvent` member is set to a manual-reset event from `CreateEvent()`.  You can then use any of the `WaitFor*()` functions to wait on the event.  If it times out, call `CancelIo()` to abort the read operation.

Comment: The limitation is: I do not want to read any data just yet. I only want to be notified about data being available. I already tried ReadFile/Ex() with a buffer length of 0 and it triggers immediately. Thanks anyway!

Comment: According to the documentation, ReadFileEx requires a handle that was opened with FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, and ReadFile behaves synchronously if the handle was not opened with FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED.  Is the actual behaviour different?

Comment: The only way I know to query a pipe for data without actually reading the data is to use `PeekNamedPipe()`, but then you lose the ability to wait on a timeout effectively, because it has no timeout so you would have to implement a manual loop instead.